# SAF - File written in parent folder, not in the right path

Tags: android, copy, parent, subdirectory, storage-access-framework

My app wants to copy a file from a private app folder to a SAF folder that was created inside an user-selected SAF folder.
Folder creation is Ok.

The copy method is:

```
public static boolean copyFileToTargetSAFFolder(Context context, String filePath, String targetFolder, String destFileName ) 
{


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(targetFolder);

    String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri);
    Log.d("target folder uri",uri.toString());
    Log.d("target folder id",docId);
    Uri dirUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, docId );
    Log.d("dir uri",dirUri.toString());
    Uri destUri = null;

    try
    {
        destUri = DocumentsContract.createDocument(context.getContentResolver(), dirUri, "*/*", destFileName);
        Log.d("dest uri",destUri.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream( destUri, "w");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);

        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)     {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

the log is:

```
target folder uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername%2Fsubfoldername

target folder id: raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/foldername

dir uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername

dest uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername%2Ffile.txt
```

It is indeed what happens on the filesystem. In fact the file is copied and created in the parent folder, not in the subfolder.
This code was from an answer on SO:

[SAF - Invalid URI error from DocumentsContract.createDocument method (FileOutputStream copy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148196/saf-invalid-uri-error-from-documentscontract-createdocument-method-fileoutput)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if it is only a workaround but if I replace

```
String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri);
```

with

```
String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
```

the method works.

```
public static boolean copyFileToTargetSAFFolder(Context context, String filePath, String targetFolder, String destFileName ) 
{


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(targetFolder);

    String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    Uri dirUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, docId );
    Uri destUri = null;

    try
    {
       destUri = DocumentsContract.createDocument(context.getContentResolver(), dirUri, "*/*", destFileName);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream( destUri, "w");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);

        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)     {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Indeed 
now log has

```
dirUri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ffoldername%2Fsubfoldername
```

the file is correctly copied inside this folder.